# In libspotify, when does the the PlaylistContainer become invalid (or: what is the lifetime of it)?

Tags: spotify, libspotify

This question is mostly a question on the workings of libspotify on a conceptual level. I have tried various (unsuccessful) pieces of code, of which I cannot get a firm grasp, because I feel I don't fully understand how the library works.

[The docs](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/group__session.html#ga319767f0b795f1c46a08390b587c5671) state that the `sp_session_playlistcontainer` gets the "playlist container for the currently logged in user". This leads me to believe that the `PlaylistContainer` is only valid in the time a user is logged in. For starters: is this correct?

The thing that is most unclear is what happens when a user is not explicitly logged out, but the connection somehow gets disrupted. For instance, when the `ConnectionState` becomes disconnected, offline or undefined and, after some time, returns to logged in.

I mostly investigated the 'disconnected scenario', and found that after returning to the logged in state, I could not get the `PlaylistContainer` to work properly again, either by keeping the original reference or retrieving a new reference. Most probably there is some error in code, but since I don't know what I should expect, I don't know what part is relevant to show here.

The question is thus: at what points in time does the `PlaylistContainer` become 'invalid', and should I get a new reference to that object? It would be nice if the answer could give insight the entire lifetime of the `PlaylistContainer`, in addition to my specific situation.